# Routing by operation

Tags: apache-camel, esb, apache-servicemix

is there any way to route a ServiceMix message by operation specified in that message?

I've tried googling it but was unable to find any way to complete this simple task, maybe I am doing it wrong in first place?

I've got an adapter that dispatches 2 types of messages. 2 other adapters have to catch them and give a response. Both messages have identical bodies (for example let it be some `<product>...</product>`) but the operation differs (for example `update` and `create`). How do I route that messages to different adapters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://fernandoribeiro.eti.br/2009/06/06/multiple-operations-in-apache-camel-routes/

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public final class SampleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() {
        from("jbi:service:http://www.fernandoribeiro.eti.br/SampleService")
            .choice()
                .when(header("jbi.operation")
                    .isEqualTo("{http://www.fernandoribeiro.eti.br}FirstOperation"))
                .when(header("jbi.operation")
                    .isEqualTo("{http://www.fernandoribeiro.eti.br}SecondOperation"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Camel XPath predicate (http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html). For example:

```
from("queue:products").  
choice().xpath("/product/[@create='true']")).to("queue:create").
otherwise().to("queue:update");
```

Comment: Sorry but I meant JBI operation, not some custom operation on my object.